# Script to merge changes made in file

Tags: merge, diff, patch

Tried
Diff -ubB -I "string" file1 file2 > file.patch

Patch -u file1 -i file.patch

Unfortunately the -I in diff only works if the string has match in hunk

I have some lines in file1 with "string" that are not there in file2 but which I want to retain

In some cases the line with "string" is inserted like this

File 2
ABCDxyz));

File 1
ABCDxyz)
*****string***
);

In this case diff -I is not able to ignore this change